# Detect a VGA monitor on windows, using DDC?

Tags: winapi, vga

Does windows provide any api calls to detect if a monitor is presently connected on the VGA port by using DDC I or DCC 2?

I am trying to figure out a way to know if a monitor is connected and turned on.

Comment: I gotta admit, I've never heard of DDC or DCC. A google search for DDC reveals an application named something like DDC which can talk to display drivers, and DCC is "Direct Client to Client" (which was an IRC helper-protocol, wasn't it?)

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Display_Data_Channel has some details

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call the [EnumDisplayDevices](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd162609(VS.85).aspx) function.

Comment: Unfortuently that function does not change in real time. I trying to detect when someone unplugs a monitor. MSDN seems to indicate use of DDC was only added to winapi in Vista.

Comment: You should've put in your question that you wanted to hook the unplug event. I just asked the same question but it turns out I'm not the first: - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1440285/how-to-detect-hot-plugging-of-monitor-in-a-win32-application
- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3267722/getting-an-event-on-monitor-hotplug-for-windows
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5981520/detect-external-display-being-connected-or-removed-under-windows-7

Answer (score 0):

Not a free solution but the only one that I've been able to find so far:

http://www.nicomsoft.com/wini2cddc/