# How to detect hot plugging of monitor in a win32 application?

Tags: c++, winapi, monitor

I need some kind of event from Windows whenever there is a monitor that's getting plugged into system. Is there any API in Windows to do that. BTW, it is an C++ application

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use  [RegisterDeviceNotification](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363431%28VS.85%29.aspx) to register for getting [WM_DEVICECHANGE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363480%28VS.85%29.aspx) notification.

Comment: It depends on how "turn off" function is implemented in the monitor and in the its driver.

Comment: Just turn off the monitor and check whether it is disappeared in the Device Manager.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it via WMI, AFAIK.  I've never tried it though so I can't give much help

[Read here for more info: MSDN - Receiving a WMI Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa393013(VS.85).aspx)