# How to programmatically scan hdmi devices on Linux?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

Our application is written in C++ and runs on Ubuntu. I need to scan all the connected HDMI devices and obtain information such as device model, serial number, etc. Can someone please point me in the right direction? Regards.

Comment: See [How to create a callback for “monitor plugged” on an intel graphics?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5469828/11654). Also check for files with `hdmi` or `extcon` in their name in `/sysfs/`.