# Unexpected result regarding Linux terminal command "/sys/class/drm/*/status"

Tags: linux, linux-device-driver, linux-mint

I executed this command in my Linux PC.

```
for p in /sys/class/drm/*/status; do con=${p%/status}; echo -n "${con#*/card?-}: "; cat $p; done
```

And this is the result.

> DP-1: disconnected
>
> DP-2: connected
>
> HDMI-A-1: connected
>
> HDMI-A-2: disconnected

My Linux PC has **two DP ports**, and I connected to two monitors.
One of the monitor is using adapter (from HDMI to DP)

Here I make a assumption, since one of the monitor is using adapter, so the result shows **HDMI-A-1** is connected, instead of both **DP** are connected.

Is my assumption correct ?

Comment: Any updates on my questions?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are trying to detect if one monitor has been disconnected?

> Here I make a assumption, since one of the monitor is using adapter,
>   so the result shows HDMI-A-1 is connected, instead of both DP are
>   connected.
>
> Is my assumption correct ?

Most likely yes.

**a)** For more debugging I would run: `lshw -short` pickup a correct class and then do e.g. `lshw -c display` what is detected by the system.

**b)** You can also try to find the manufacturer of your device (you will probably need to install `edid-decode` for that):

`ls /sys/class/drm/*/edid | xargs -n 1 edid-decode | grep Manufacturer:`

When you unplug monitor or have a linux in virutal machine (like in my case) you will see a message: 
`Manufacturer: @@@ Model 0 Serial Number 0`

**c)** You can also try disconnecting the monitor with the adapter and monitor it.   You can do that by monitoring the change via `udevadm monitor --property`.

If you are trying to create a callback in linux I recommend reading the already answered [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5469828/how-to-create-a-callback-for-monitor-plugged-on-an-intel-graphics).

Comment: I am wonder why it is not displaying both DP is connected, because both DP port on PC is connected. (although one of DP port is actually a adapter that convert HDMI to DP)

Comment: @AnsonTan I would need to know more about the HDMI converter, could you post some details?  I have tried it on my laptop and the converter and I got `LVDS` - connected the notebook screen and the `DP-1` (with the converter) - connected.  My converter is HP original DP 1.2 to HDMI 1.4 adapter PN:778968-001 (https://www.amazon.com/HP-DisplayPort-HDMI-1-4-Adapter/dp/B00L9BCH00) so it is not always so.  In your case I think the reason is the adapter you have.  Could you try connecting and disconnecting the monitors?  What report the monitors the same way?  What monitor(s) are you connecting?

Comment: @AnsonTan What graphic card are you connecting to?