# Getting an event on monitor hotplug for windows

Tags: .net, winapi, pinvoke

I'd really like to listen for when a monitor gets hotplugged like when a laptop docs or has a external monitor plugged in.

I'm hoping I can do this in .net maybe with some pinvoke.

Comment: Oh I've had a little more luck with a similar question differently worded: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5981520/detect-external-display-being-connected-or-removed-under-windows-7

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Detect external display being connected or removed under Windows 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5981520/detect-external-display-being-connected-or-removed-under-windows-7)

Answer (score 0):

As said [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33762140/what-is-the-notification-when-the-number-of-monitors-changes/33762334#33762334):

When adding a monitor on Windows 7 x64 I see registered messages "UxdDisplayChangeMessage" and "HotplugDetected". You can use [RegisterWindowMessage](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644947(v=vs.85).aspx) to get the identifier for these messages and later just handle messages with this identifier.