# What is the notification when the number of monitors changes?

Tags: c++, c, windows, winapi

I'm curious, what is the Win32 notification that is broadcast when the number of monitors in the system changes? I thought it was [WM_DISPLAYCHANGE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd145210(v=vs.85).aspx) but I was wrong.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This is quite easy to check with `Microsoft Spy++`. In my case I checked on Windows 7 x64 with two monitors connected and switching the second monitor off and on again.

When removing a monitor you will see a `WM_DISPLAYCHANGE`, but not when adding a monitor.

You will see a `WM_DEVICECHANGE` with `DBT_DEVNODES_CHANGED` (after [RegisterDeviceNotification](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363431(v=vs.85).aspx)).

You will see `WM_SETTINGCHANGE` for `SPI_SETWORKAREA` and `SPI_ICONVERTICALSPACING`.

And you will see registered messages "UxdDisplayChangeMessage" and "HotplugDetected" (second one only when adding monitor). You can use [RegisterWindowMessage](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644947(v=vs.85).aspx) to get the identifier for these messages.

Comment: An edge case I can think of is adding a monitor that is mirroring the display instead of extending it.  Would it still get `SPI_SETWORKAREA` if the work area isn't changing?

Comment: @indiv I don't know. The results are from tests I just made. You can easily check that yourself with Spy++. If I should guess, I'ld expect to see UxdDisplayChangeMessage, HotplugDetected and WM_DEVICECHANGE, but not WM_DISPLAYCHANGE and WM_SETTINGCHANGE.

Comment: @WernerHenze: Thanks. `WM_SETTINGCHANGE` with `wParam == SPI_SETWORKAREA` seems to do the trick for adding and removing monitors on all OS's down to XP. I'm not sure about the rest of your proposed solutions though. If Spy++ shows something, it doesn't mean that it's a documented approach.

Comment: Wasn't able to get any of these messages to be shown. :(

Comment: @Adrian I suggest opening a new question where you provide your code and reference this question here.

Comment: "removing monitor you see WM_DISPLAYCHANGE, but not when adding a monitor" -------> This information is NOT TRUE. At least not on Win7! I tried it. Disconnecting the monitor sends the signal. Connecting the monitor back, sends the signal again. Can anyone else confirm my experiment?   Also, the documentation does not backup your statement: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/gdi/wm-displaychange