# Get new connected display via existing IDXGIDevice

Tags: c++, directx, directx-11, dxgi

I have a program that creates `ID3D11Device` device on start and destroys on shutdown. I encountered the issue when I connected the second monitor after `ID3D11Device` was created.
In this simplified piece of code it enumerates adapter outputs and this enumeration returns only one monitor, the first one that had been connected before program started.

**A**

```
IDXGIDevice* DXGIDevice;
D3D11Device->QueryInterface(IID_IDXGIDevice, (void**)&DXGIDevice);

IDXGIAdapter* DXGIAdapter;
DXGIDevice->GetAdapter(&DXGIAdapter);

IDXGIOutput* Output;
int i = 0;
while (DXGIAdapter->EnumOutputs(i, &Output) != DXGI_ERROR_NOT_FOUND)
{
    DXGI_OUTPUT_DESC desc;
    Output->GetDesc(&desc);

    PrintMonitor(desc.Monitor);
}
```

But if I try manually create factory and get main adapter, it enumerates both monitors.

**B**

```
IDXGIFactory* DXGIFactory;
IDXGIAdapter* DXGIAdapter;

CreateDXGIFactory(__uuidof(IDXGIFactory), (void**)&DXGIFactory);
factory->EnumAdapters(0, &DXGIAdapter);

IDXGIOutput* Output;
int i = 0;
while (DXGIAdapter->EnumOutputs(i, &Output) != DXGI_ERROR_NOT_FOUND)
{
    DXGI_OUTPUT_DESC desc;
    Output->GetDesc(&desc);

    PrintMonitor(desc.Monitor);
}
```

My question is: is this possible "refresh" outputs list of adapter that was get from `DXGIDevice` device without this device recreation, and see any monitors plug-in/plug-out in code like the first one (**A**)?

Comment: If you have Windows 10 1809  you can use IDXGIFactory7::RegisterAdaptersChangedEvent https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/dxgi1_6/nf-dxgi1_6-idxgifactory7-registeradapterschangedevent otherwise just poll (recreate the factory each time). This is demonstrated in this official sample https://github.com/microsoft/DirectX-Graphics-Samples/tree/master/Samples/Desktop/D3D12xGPU of if you have a window: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33762140/what-is-the-notification-when-the-number-of-monitors-changes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The method `IDXGIFactory1::IsCurrent()` should help.  If it returns FALSE, then you should destroy and re-create the factory to refresh the information. Just check it after each all to `Present`.

I use this method to support HDR10 output in my *directx-vs-templates* project. See [DX11](https://github.com/walbourn/directx-vs-templates/blob/master/d3d11game_win32_dr/DeviceResources.cpp) and [DX12](https://github.com/walbourn/directx-vs-templates/blob/master/d3d12game_win32_dr/DeviceResources.cpp).