# How can i detect to what source my monitor is set to now?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, generics

Now my monitor is set to DVI-D and i know it's my pc.
But for example my playstation 4 is connected to HDMI 1
What i want to do is when i change my monitor source to HDMI 1 detect it and when i change it back to DVI-D detect it to so i can then know when my monitor source is on the pc or on the ps4.

What i tried so far is this.
I added a timer in my designer i'm running the timer for 40 seconds and in the timer calling a method:

```
int counttimer2 = 0;
    private void timer2_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (counttimer2 == 40)
        {
            w.Close();
            timer2.Stop();
        }
        DetectScreenName();
        counttimer2 += 1;
    }
```

And the method DetectScreenName:

```
private void DetectScreenName()
        {
            if (counttimer2 < 40)
            {
                SelectQuery q = new SelectQuery("SELECT Name, DeviceID, Description FROM Win32_DesktopMonitor");
                using (ManagementObjectSearcher mos = new ManagementObjectSearcher(q))
                {
                    foreach (ManagementObject mo in mos.Get())
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("{0}, {1}, {2}",
                            mo.Properties["Name"].Value.ToString(),
                            mo.Properties["DeviceID"].Value.ToString(),
                            mo.Properties["Description"].Value.ToString());
                        results.Add(mo.Properties["Name"].Value.ToString());
                        results.Add(mo.Properties["DeviceID"].Value.ToString());
                        results.Add(mo.Properties["Description"].Value.ToString());
                        w.WriteLine(mo.Properties["Name"].Value.ToString());
                        w.WriteLine(mo.Properties["DeviceID"].Value.ToString());
                        w.WriteLine(mo.Properties["Description"].Value.ToString());
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

On the text file i'm writing the results to see the changes all the results are the same:

Generic PnP Monitor
DesktopMonitor1
Generic PnP Monitor

Every second i see:

Generic PnP Monitor
DesktopMonitor1
Generic PnP Monitor

It didn't change when i switch the monitor source to HDMI 1

Answer (score 0):

When you switch the source of your monitor, for your computer nothing changes - it is as if the monitor is switched off.

Unfortunately, you can't reliably detect that, as explained in [Is there any way to detect the monitor state in Windows (on or off)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203355/is-there-any-way-to-detect-the-monitor-state-in-windows-on-or-off) and [Detect external display being connected or removed under Windows 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5981520/detect-external-display-being-connected-or-removed-under-windows-7).